# Firefox always show any numeric input as NAN

Tags: firefox, nan

I installed a new fresh windows 8.1 (64bit) and then install Firefox 33.1.1 without any add-on or extensions after that. but Firefox show every numeric input (type="number") as `NAN` even without any JavaScript code. (other browser haven't any problem with that.)
for example code below show as this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="number" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: why not just set an initial value of `0`?

Comment: value="0" or any other values doesn't help. it's still stick on NAN!

Comment: In my FF 35 it just shows an empty field. Maybe this bug is fixed in later versions of FF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a bug in Firefox!

i think this problem exists for the Persian language (or maybe arabic)

To fix this problem in windows, set **Decimal Symbol** to Dot "**.**"

**Note:** Region > Additional Setting

But in my opinion, now is the best solution use **type="text"** instead of **type"number"** for inputs

Comment: And this seems to be just a problem with the **view**. The `input.value` and `input.valueAsNumber` seem to work as expected. I'm looking for a way to detect this bug and show the user a message about it. But it seems there is no clue for that!

Answer (score 2):

I see It`s happening in Firefox only when settings of Windows in **Control Panel** --> **Language** --> **Change date, time, or number formats** --> **Format** is set to **Persian**
(I have Win 8.1 + FireFox 39.0-fa)

Comment: I guess this is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Your meta tag is inappropriate for HTML5. There is a specific `META Charset` tag for HTML5. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp
- In HTML you must not use XML closing tags `/>`

You can also help yourself by adding more content to your HTML, such as adding an `encytpye` to the form and more:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="number" name="larry" min="0" max="100" value="">
</form>
```

Try that syntax and see if it corrects.

Comment: I tested it not working if i copy paste a long number